# how to use mysql variable inside visual studio (Query Builder)?

Tags: mysql, variables

when i execute this query in mysql it's work OK :

```
SET @s:=0;
SELECT `debt`, `credit`, @ s : = (`debt` - `credit`) + @ s AS `balance`
FROM `recordsdetails`;
```

but when i use it into (visual studio Query Builder) 
i see this : Error in SELECT clause: expression near '@'.
             Error in FROM clause: near ';'.
             Unable to parse query text.
and `balance`=NULL

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespaces:

```
SET @s:=0;
SELECT debt, credit, @s:=(debt-credit)+@s AS balance FROM recordsdetails;
```

Comment: Still the same problem , balance =Null

Comment: I think the problem because of the variable @s

Answer (score 0):

First you must declare variable using `=` and then assign value using `:=`:

```
SET @s = 0;
SELECT debt, credit, @s:=(debt-credit)+@s AS balance FROM recordsdetails;
```

Comment: the problem still exist !!!
   - can we turn it into a VIEW in the mysql server and call it by (Query Builder) as result ?
thank you for the information